# My variables black1 and black2 giving me the wrong answers in c++?

Tags: c++

My professor is forcing me to use a program called RAPTOR, which preety much creates and executes flow charts and psuedocode. And I'm stuck converting my flowchart, insted of writing in the actual language. I finally got my program to compile, but now it wont give me the same results as in the RAPTOR program, and my black1 variable keeps returning 0, where as black2 keeps spitting out a number like 1,000. Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int trials;
   int first;
   string bag;
   int j;
   float percent;
   string temp;
   int black2;
   int runs;
   int l;
   int black1;
   int firstdraw;
   int c;
   string possible;
   int seconddraw;
   srand(time(NULL));
   l = bag.length();
   int r = rand() % 4;

   possible ="bw";
   runs =0;
   while (!(runs>9))
   {
      black1 =0;
      black2 =0;
      runs =runs+1;
  trials =0;
  while (!(trials==1000))
  {
     trials =trials+1;
     bag ="bbwww";
     l = bag.length();
     c =1;
     temp =" ";
     while (!(c==5))
     {
        j = r ;
        temp[1] = bag[c];
        bag[c] = bag[j];
        bag[j] = temp[1];
        c =c+1;
     }
     c =1;
     j = r;
     firstdraw =bag[j];
     if (firstdraw==possible[1])
     {
        black1 = black1+1;
        first = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        first = 0;
     }
     while (!(j>l-1))
     {
        bag[j] = bag[j + 1];
        j =j+1;
     }
     l =l-1;
     j = r;
     seconddraw = bag[j];
     if (seconddraw==possible[1] && first==1)
     {
        black2 =black2+1;
     }
     else
     {
     }
  }
  percent = 100.0 * black2/black1;
  cout << black2 << " " << black1 << endl;
  cout << "Percentage for run #" << runs << " and " << trials << " trials: %" << percent << endl;   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.G. `g++ -Wall -g`). Learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`). And don't expect others to do your homework. BTW, it is better for you to take time to *understand* things.

Comment: We've never spoken about debuggers in class, and I don't expect others, I just wanted to help, my professor tried helping me, but all he did was make the code compiled, and didn't help at all in getting the same results from when I executed the flowchart. this is my first semester in coding, and I'm trying my best to understand it, but it's hard when they baby you into things, and add all of these handicaps. my apologies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry but *I won't fix your whole code*, I made it more readable, removed that ugly `using namespace std;` and left some comments for you. Check this out, fix your code, and take a look into some tutorials if needed. I've gotten a debug assertion over and over again with this code. Guessing you never runned any debugger and just had Release mode on.

**Also don't forget to initialize the variables. You risk undefined behaviour.**

> These two strings walk into a bar and sit down. The bartender says, "So what'll it be?"
>   The first string says, "I think I'll have a beer quag fulk boorg jdk^CjfdLk jk3s d#f67howe%^U r89nvy~~owmc63^Dz x.xvcu"
>   "Please excuse my friend," the second string says, "He isn't null-terminated."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int trials = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int black2 = 0;
    int runs = 0;
    int black1 = 0;
    int firstdraw = 0;
    int seconddraw = 0;
    float percent = 0.0f;

    std::string temp = "\0";
    std::string bag = "\0";
    std::string possible = "\0";

    srand (time(NULL));
    l = bag.length();

    fflush(stdin); // You may want to do this to get random numbers from rand() otherwise it may use the same number over and over again
    int r = 0;
    r = rand() % 4;

    possible = "bw";
    runs = 0;
    while (!(runs > 9))
    {
        black1 = 0;
        black2 = 0;
        runs = runs + 1;  //Why no for loop ?
        trials = 0;

        while (!(trials == 1000))
        {
            trials = trials + 1; //Why no for loop ?
            bag ="bbwww";
            l = bag.length();
            c = 1;
            temp =" ";
            while (!(c == 5))
            {
                j = r;
                temp[1] = bag[c]; // temp[1] <- debug assertion, can't work
                bag[c] = bag[j];
                bag[j] = temp[1]; // temp[1] <- debug assertion, can't work either
                c = c + 1;
            }
            c = 1;
            j = r;
            firstdraw = bag[j];

            if (firstdraw == possible[1])
            {
                black1 = black1 + 1;
                first = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                first = 0;
            }
            while (!(j > l - 1))
            {
                bag[j] = bag[j + 1]; //Will most likely cause a debug assertion too...
                j = j + 1;
            }
            l = l - 1;
            j = r;
            seconddraw = bag[j];

            if (seconddraw == possible[1] && first==1)
            {
                black2 = black2 + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //Not needed !?!
            }
        }
        percent = 100.0 * black2 / black1;
        std::cout << black2 << " " << black1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Percentage for run #" << runs << " and " << trials << " trials: %" << percent << std::endl;
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your citation about strings in a bar. Where did you take that from?

Comment: I've had read a familar joke somewhere on MSDN. Couldn't find it anymore so I just typed in google `nullterminated string joke` and this came out.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the help. Alot of the while loops are there instad of for and stuff, is because it's part of the assignment, since I'm converting this from a flowchart. which just makes everything alot more difficult and dumb. thank you very much though, I think this will help me alot!

Comment: If your question is solved by this, please click the big tick under the vote score.